# Why is it OK not to Dispose a UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, idisposable, asp.net-identity-2

The default MVC 5 + Identity 2.1 project contains this line (in Startup.Auth.cs):

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

...where the static `Create` method is defined (in IdentityConfig.cs) as follows:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
     ...
}
```

Notice how a new `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` is created there, and passed to the `ApplicationUserManager` constructor. Note also that `UserStore<T>` is disposable (the base class implements `IDisposable`).

This struck me as odd, because I wondered who was responsible for disposing of that newly-created `UserStore`. I expected that `ApplicationUserManager` (or it's base class) must dispose of it when it itself is disposed. But no: I looked at the source and it seems not. So *nobody* disposes of that instance!

Why is that OK? When would you *not* want to dispose of an instance of a class that implements `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is OK because `UserStore` is actually wrapping Entity Framework's `DbContext` class. And while `DbContext` is also `Disposable` but [refer to this blog post](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html) disposing `DbContext` is not mandatory. Also it is worth pointing out that disposing injected object is not good idea in fact it is injector's responsibility to manage the object's lifetime. Therefore it is obvious `UserManager` dose not dispose `UserStore` in this case.

Comment: Have you read the comments on that post? They outline some very good reasons for calling Dispose on the context even though it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: I was in no way suggesting that the `ApplicationUserManager` *should* be responsible for disposing the context - that's not the behavior I'd like to see. However, there are classes in the framework that behave like this.

Comment: Of course disposing a disposable object is a good idea. I tried to say, in this case, disposing `DbContext` is not necessary and you could omit it. Just like they did in this example. By the way if you really want to dispose `UserStore` simply put it in  `Owin` context and retrieve it in Create method. `Owin` context manager will dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

Little late but I have been creating an MVC 5 project and can confirm that Dispose on the UserStore is being called every time a http request is complete.

I believe it is coming from the IOwinContext reference when the ApplicationUserManager is created. Specifically the context being used to get the DbContext:

```
new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
```

In the Startup class the IAppBuilder object is configured to CreatePerOwinContext:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

If you override the UserStore Dispose method:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

After the base.Dispose(disposing) executes, the UserStore's Context property becomes null.